# Closing an image window

Tags: matlab

```
function [x, y] = get_one_point_from_image(input_image)
    % read image
    I = im2double(input_image);
    handle = subplot(1,1,1);
    imshow(I);

    % let the user pick one point
    [x,y] = ginput(1);

    % round to integer to match required input by regiongrowing function
    x = round(x);
    y = round(y);

    close(handle);
end
```

This routine pops up a window.

I need that window to be closed when the selection of a point is done.

But, this routine is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not close the "subplot", you need to close the figure.

You can always `close gcf` (gfc=get current figure), or if you want it to be more reliable, create the figure in the beginning as `handle=figure;` and close that.

Note: Creating a 1x1x1 subplot makes no sense